# How to show input box after checkbox is clicked [HTML]

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code inside my body - I'd like to show the input box only when the checkbox is checked, and then disappear again once unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="exercheckbox">THISCHECKBOX

<!-- show this input box --> <input type="text" name="reps">
```

I've seen ways to do it using javascript however I have no experience in this language so I'm not sure how to implement and adapt that code so that it works with my checkbox. Is there a way to do it using HTML? If not how would I do it using javascript?

Comment: You can't do this with pure HTML.  The Javascript required is very trivial, you could piece it together easily by just reading answers on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do with a pure CSS Solution like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="exercheckbox" id="exercheckbox">THISCHECKBOX</input>

<input type="text" name="reps" id="reps" />
```

CSS:

```
#reps{
    display: none;
}
 #exercheckbox:checked ~ #reps{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This stops working however when I add a <h3> label around the <input> checkbox, how would I get around this?

Comment: <h3><input type="checkbox" name="exercheckbox" id="exercheckbox"><?php echo $name; ?></h3>
      <input type="text" name="reps" id="reps">

Comment: Am afraid , you cant do that way , CSS is checking for any siblings of checkbox to hide n show based on the checked state. If you want to do this exactly propably you'll have to just style the checkbox like h3 instead of using h3 tag. Or atleast put them in the same level.